# Python list gives error in one instant but is okay in the other

Tags: python, list

```
a=[2,3,4,9a] #error
a=[2,3,4,9b] # error
.
.
.
a=[2,3,4,9j] # okay
a=[2,3,4,9k] # error
.
.
a=[2,3,4,9z] # error
```

I understand why others are giving errors but why is `a=[2,3,4,9j]` okay

Comment: Why should this question get downvoted. Isn't it a genuine question. Please post a comment after you downvote any question.

Comment: `9l` is perfectly valid. See my post below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`9j` is the imaginary number (complex number) so it is a valid literal. Other ones are not. May be you want strings in which case you should write `'9a'`, `'9b'`, etc. with quotes (single or double).

Comment: @Ankur Because the syntax is `<number>j`, not `<number>i`.  The `j` syntax comes from electrical engineering, where `j` is used to represent the imaginary unit, rather than `i`.

Comment: @Ankur While in math we may consider 9i to be complex (by convention), Python has a stricter syntax. If you lookup the syntax of a [complex literal](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#complex) you'll find only `<number>j` is considered complex and not `<number>i`, as already mentioned by @AaronDufour above.

Answer (score 2):

See [this section](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex) of the docs:

> There are four distinct numeric types: **plain integers, long integers, floating point numbers, and complex numbers**. [...]
>
> Numbers are created by numeric literals or as the result of built-in functions and operators. Unadorned integer literals (including binary, hex, and octal numbers) yield plain integers unless the value they denote is too large to be represented as a plain integer, in which case they yield a long integer. Integer literals with an **'L'** or **'l'** suffix yield **long integers** ('L' is preferred because 1l looks too much like eleven!). Numeric literals containing a decimal point or an exponent sign yield floating point numbers. Appending **'j'** or **'J'** to a numeric literal yields a **complex number with a zero real part**. A complex numeric literal is the sum of a real and an imaginary part.

Therefore, these two are in fact valid expressions:

```
a=[2,3,4,9j] # okay
a=[2,3,4,9l] # no error
```

Answer (score 1):

You've stumbled upon complex number notation in python. For some reason, `j` is used instead of `i` for imaginary numbers.

Comment: It's the age old debate among Mathematicians and Electrical Engineers. Mathematicians use 'i' and Electrical Engineers use 'j'.

Comment: *That's* where it comes from? Thanks, I had no idea! :-)

Comment: In Electrical Engineering and Control Theory so as to not confuse with electric current which also uses `i`, `j` was the preferred notation